# Konsole terminal on Gnome 3 is old and some icons are missing

Tags: command-line, gnome, konsole

I'm using `konsole` as a terminal emulator and I love it. In my opinion it is just better then the default `gnome-terminal` so I would like to keep using it on `Ubuntu v20.04` where I have `GNOME v3.36.3`.

The `konsole` version on repositories is old (`v19.12.3`) while the latest is `v20.08.1`. So the first question is: is there a way to install the latest version without having to compile the sources? Maybe a PPA?

I also discovered that there are some missing icons:

[image]

[image]

[image]

so the second question is: is there any package or theme that I am missing and may install in order to fix that issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to upgrade Konsole? Upgrading it most likely would not solve the issue with theme?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi , yes I know, no specific reason, just to have the latest version.

Comment: Then you can try KDE Neon

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu only provides security updates to packages, once a stable version is released.

The [Kubuntu Backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) hosts some newer KDE packages for older version of Ubuntu, but it does not host Konsole 20.08.

In principle, you can update packages using the repository of Ubuntu 20.10 (not released yet), but that is not recommended. If you really need the latest KDE softwares, you can either update to Ubuntu 20.10 when it is released, or use KDE Neon (which is not an official flavor of Ubuntu).

To use a uniform theme in GNOME and KDE softwares, you can use [adwaita-qt](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=adwaita-qt) theme.

`sudo apt install adwaita-qt`

[image]
(Image taken from [GitHub repo](https://github.com/FedoraQt/adwaita-qt) of adwaita-qt)

Comment: Even with `ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports` the latest konsole version available is the one that I already have.